# Programmatically find best-matching resource at runtime

Tags: android, screen, hdpi, mdpi

Is it possible to find the best-matching resource Programmatically at run-time ?

For example I have some device that have screen properties that makes perfect match for layout-normal-mdpi. How can I, at run time, read that that specification ? For example for my screen the result should be normal screen size and for the density mdpi as  perfect match.

Comment: yes programmatically , sorry I click on wrong item of the context menu in the spell checker list and I didn't noticed :(...

Comment: @Kurru not jet, but it is still freaking me out, did you find something ? if you do please provide some links here,Thanks

Comment: @Lukap If only... I've been told several times you can't do it though... But with Android that can mean that people dont know how YET...

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be done automatically by creating qualified resource folders. If you create multiple resource folders for different conditions the device will read your conditions and choose the best version of the resource for it.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Yes but this is not programmatically. This is made by the nameing conventions